# Comparing listview column values with another listview column values and display the column value instead of other if it matches

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, compare, contacts

I have a list view that shows **contacts**- `name` and `number` are the columns. I have another listview that shows **messages**- `phone number` (from where the message is received), `message` being the columns. Now when I populate my message listview, I want to compare the phone number column with the contact list number column and then replace the message listview's number column with the contact name if there is a match.

Is this possible? Please provide solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this can help you:

```
           if (messagelist.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < messagelist.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    string mnum = messagelist.Items[i].Text;

                    for (int j = 0; j < contactlist.Items.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (contactlist.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text == mnum)
                        {
                            messagelist.Items[i].Text = contactlist.Items[j].Text;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

I assumed that the contactlist has number in its 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

I would first `join` the two `lists` on number/phone number:

```
var matchingList = (from c in ContactList
                    join m in MessageList on c.Number equals m.PhoneNumber
                    select new {ContactName = c.Name
                              , ContactNumber = c.Number
                              , Message = m.Message
                              , PhoneNumber = m.PhoneNumber } );
```

Now you have a `list` of all matching `Contact.Number` and `Message.PhoneNumber`.

Now you can loop through the items and set the `Name`:

```
MessageList.Foreach( x => 
{
    var matchedItem = matchingList.FirstOrDefault( y => y.Massage == x.Message && y.PhoneNumber == x.PhoneNumber);

    if(matchedItem != null)
    {
        x.PhoneNumber = matchedItem.Name
    }
});
```

NOTE: Not tested. Just something to work off.

Hope this helps.